# Solving exponential integral with two variables (x and r)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Prove that $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^r}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-ln(x)^2}{2}}dx=e^\frac{r^2}{2}$

I tried integrating by parts, with $u=e^{\frac{-ln(x)^2}{2}}$ and $v' =$ the remaining. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

\Use the replacement $\log x = t$, then $x = \mathrm{e}^t$ and $dt = dx/x$, so your integral becomes
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{r t} \frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} dt $$

In which you should recognize a standard normal distribution. Apply rules for Gaussian integration and you're done!

EDIT: Here is how to solve the final integral. A neat trick in Gaussian integration.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2/2 + rt}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dt $$
*Complete the square* at the exponent as $-t^2/2 + rt +r^2/2 - r^2/2 = -(t - r)^2/2 + r^2/2$, we get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(t-r)^2/2 + r^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dt =e^{r^2/2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(t-r)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dt$$
Note that what is left is the total area under a Gaussian density with mean r and variance 1, so the integral is $1$. QED

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: The integral is $-b^a / x^a$, you need to assume that $a<0$ so that the part for $x\to 0$ converges. Post it as a question and I can give you the details (if you want).